# .NET on a locked down computer

Tags: .net, runtime

Might seem like a bizarre request, but is there anyway to run .NET apps on a locked down machine without installing the runtime? If a set of my users is going to working on machines that are totally locked down, no .NET runtime and no way to install it, is there anyway to 'host' the runtime?

I was thinking along the lines of portable usb apps or something?

Anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: See this: [Running .net based application without .net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework/953174)

Comment: This is not a dupe of that. It's essentially, "Is there any way to install .NET framework without admin previliges?" which is a different question.

Comment: @ajmastrean - Your link it broken because of the trailing ">"

Comment: (fixed) I believe it's a duplicate because the situation is "no way to install" the framework. The answers very similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199/net-framework-dependency

Answer (score 2):

No.  The runtime must be installed by someone, either by the default windows installation on the box, Windows Update, or an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [Mono](http://mono-project.com). It'll work with a local, private copy.

Comment: Mehrdad, you mean I can just copy it into a folder and run my application, without running an installer?

Comment: Yes. Btw, you can't just double click the executable after that, but you could create a batch file (or anything like that) that runs `mono assembly.exe`.

Comment: thanks for the tip on mono, I'll have to check that out. unfortunately this app has already been written in c# and uses a lot of winforms stuff that i dont think will translate

Answer (score 1):

There are some commercial tools.
For example: http://www.xenocode.com/Products/Postbuild-for-NET/ but I never try it.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only chance coding in something that doesn't need a runtime: C++ / Delphi, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install the .NET runtime, don't write a .NET app. It's really that simple. There are other choices that don't require the framework.

Comment: Yeah, obviously, but that's not what I asked. The app has already been written in .NET and you don't just rewrite a 2000 man hour app before you look for a shim.

Comment: How do you write a 2000 man hour app, and only then find out you need to run it on machines not permitted to use the Framework?

Comment: The app was written and went live on hundreds of machines that DO have the framework. But then the client decided she wanted to deploy it to machines in another building, and they have a strict set of security requirements and thus no framework.