# WPF embed .net libraries into exe file

Tags: wpf, dependencies

Is it possible to embed all .net dependencies to the final exe file because I want it to run on every windows machine even without preinstalled .net?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199/net-framework-dependency for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and setup the dependencies, so that it installs the prerequisited .Net framework.

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce is good for dealing with the deployment of your application.

To **embed** all .net dependencies you can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) or, even better, this [approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) by Jeffrey Richter (which is recommended from inside the ILMerge website too).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the lagality of this but you can possibly use reflection to get the code from the parts of the .NET framework which you are using and re-create them as your own classes. Then use those classes when building your application.

Edit: I am not sure that you can reflect the entire .net framework though.